# IATA rule regarding passenger right to drinking water

Tags: air-travel, food-and-drink, tap-water, low-cost-carriers, iata

As we know, according to IATA passengers allowed to carry no more than 100 ml of liquids on board. Yet when traveling with low-cost airlines, you are not offered any water on board. This is quite harmful, considering the dry air in the cabin. Being used to my country laws and social norms that allow anybody to ask for a free glass of water in any place that serves food, it sounds strange that I don't seem have the official right to ask for a glass of drinking water during the flight. Are there any IATA regulations or subject, or is it based purely on airline good will decision?

Comment: Have you tried asking the flight attendants?  "Not offering" isn't the same as "not available upon request".

Comment: I would feel much better to know my rights before I ask something.

Comment: "passengers allowed to carry no more than 100 ml of liquids on board" Where does it say this? If you're referring to the limits at the security check, nobody hinders you from bringing an empty bottle through security and filling it up with water after security. In fact, e.g. at US airports you find very often water taps to exactly do that. Otherwise just buy a bottle of water in one of the many shops in the secure area.

Comment: Additionally it of course depends on the airline that you use. If you use low cost carrier, very often nowadays no food and no drinks are included in the ticket price. So you don't get free water, but you can of course buy any drink you want.

Comment: @dunni you are right, and this is what I do usually, but sometimes I forget to   pour out the water from bottles, so I don't have anything to fill. And I don't think that paying 2.5 euro for a small water bottle is fair.

Comment: You can always book regular carriers, where food and drink is included in the price. With low cost carriers, you have the advantage of low prices with the disadvantage of low service.

Comment: @dunni Sorry, I couldn't find where in the question above I ask for an advice on airline. I just wanted to know, whether there is any law on this subject.

Comment: The IATA best practices guide has only rules about serving alcohol (http://www.iata.org/publications/Documents/cabin-operations-safety-bp-guide-2015.pdf). If you're asking about a country specific law, you should specify the country, otherwise it would be too broad. But i can tell you that at least for germany, there is no such law.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to know. You can extract this to an answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IATA best practices guide (http://www.iata.org/publications/Documents/cabin-operations-safety-bp-guide-2015.pdf) has only rules about serving alcohol to passengers. So it is safe to assume, that there is no other IATA rule regarding drink service. When it comes to laws, each law would be country specific. At least Germany doesn't have such a law, which would require airlines to provide free water.